# Converting BNF to EBNF

Tags: grammar, bnf, ebnf

I need to know how to convert the next BNF to EBNF so it will help me understand more how they work

```
S-> aI1I2 | epsilon
I1-> I1e | b
I2-> cd | cS
```

note: epsilon means the empty set

Comment: Why don't you try yourself? Wikipedia has extensive articles on both BNF and EBNF. If you're having trouble, come back with a more specific question, because this now reads as "could someone do this for me". Good luck!

Comment: See also [How to convert BNF to EBNF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14922242/how-to-convert-bnf-to-ebnf), which has an answer that describes (outlines) EBNF and illustrates the process.  The 'BNF' in this question is under-defined though its meaning can be guessed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert BNF to EBNF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14922242/how-to-convert-bnf-to-ebnf)

Answer (score 3):

Please consider these:

- [Cheat Sheet](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/teaching/archive/compilation-ssc/2003/exam/)
- [EBNF to BNF tricks](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/teaching/archive/compilation-ssc/2000/part4/parsing/node3.html).