# BNF to standard EBNF

Tags: bnf, ebnf

I am converting BNF dialect 2 to standard EBNF and making the grammar as simple as possible from this problem below.

```
  <state> -> <abc> | <abc>;
  <state> -> <def> | <def>;
  <state> -> <ghi> | <ghi>;
```

here is my attempt that I followed along page 131 in my textbook
http://umsl.edu/~mfrp9/misc/cpl.pdf

```
<state> -> (<abc> | <abc>)(<def> | <def)(<ghi> | <ghi>);
```

Is this a correct solution and is there a simpler solution than this with {...} for repeated?

Also I noticed in this post [How to convert BNF to EBNF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14922242/how-to-convert-bnf-to-ebnf) compared to the example above in my textbook removed <...> in the post and in my book it didn't? does it matter or what is the situation?

Comment: The BNF rules are a little odd; `<abc> | <abc>` is pretty much the same as `<abc>`, isn't it?

Comment: Of course I missed the obvious. So it should be (abc)(def)(ghi);?

Comment: I think it should probably be `abc | def | ghi`, shouldn't it?  Any one of those is valid as a state, but not several of them together.  If it is homework, it might be as well to check whether there's an error in the 3 original rules; they are unorthodox in the extreme, but might be written like that to catch you out.