# BNF grammar for a palindrome

Tags: bnf, ebnf

I need help with a non-extended BNF grammar:

- Σ = {a,b}
- L = {ω ɛ Σ^* | such that w is equal to the reverse of ω}

For example, the strings aba, bab, and ababa are in the language, but string ababab is not.

I am not sure if this is a solution but this is what I found online and I am wondering if I am heading in the right direction:

```
<palindrome> ::= a <palindrome> a | b <palindrome> b |
                 c <palindrome> c | d <palindrome> d | 
                 e <palindrome> e | ...
                                  | z <palindrome> z
<palindrome> ::= <letter>
<letter>     ::= a | b | c | ... | y | z
```

Comment: @arkascha it's not homework question. It's one of the practice exam question that i am trying to resolve before i take exam next week.

Comment: @arkascha is this the answer - <palindrome> ::= a <palindrome> a | b <palindrome> b |
                   c <palindrome> c | d <palindrome> d | 
                   e <palindrome> e | ...
                                    | z <palindrome> z
  <palindrome> ::= <letter>
  <letter>     ::= a | b | c | ... | y | z

Comment: @arkascha would appreciate even if you can guide me a little bit. The problem here is i am trying to find possible information to solve this question and have no clue on how to resolve this. I posted a possible resolution wondering if you can tell me if that is right ?

Comment: @arkascha yes w stands for strings and starting should be with left brace { and ending with right brace }. Summation would be sigma

Comment: Sigma? Can't spot that...

Comment: Your answer does not seem right... what about non-latin characters? You are trying to create a non countable solution set by iteration. That cannot work.

Comment: Please also add your proposed solution to the question, so that it get's more readable. Thanks!

Comment: @arkascha yes i edited necessary part. May i know then what would be right solution then ?

Comment: It is _not_ a correct solution. Besides what I mentioned above it does not contain words with an even number of characters (example: "abba").

Comment: What is the notation of "arbitrary but fixed" in BNF again? (Sorry if the phrase is unknown, I am translating from my native language to Englisch...)

Comment: fixed would be Σ = {a,b}

Comment: No, that is not what I meant. I meant "an arbitrary but fixed character". Typical mathematical expression. Should be the same in formal language theory, shouldn't it?

Comment: Your example gives you all odd-length palindromes for the alphabet Σ = { a,b,c,...,x,y,z }.  You want to restrict it to just the alphabet Σ = {a,b}, and add in something to match even length palindromes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least you have to include the words with an even number of characters, so:

```
<palindrome> ::= a | b | aa | bb | a<palindrome>a | b<palindrome>b
```

Comment: I hear you so if you can walk me through what would be the right way of doing it ?

Comment: That is why I asked about the "arbitrary but fixed" expression. Can't find it on google. Darn, too long ago :-) Looking for an expression to express that "a" in the first line appears before and after the symbol, where "a" can be an arbitrary but fixed character. However a character is defined. That would save the enumeration which feels wrong to me.

Comment: can u tell me if this would be right solution - aabb

a aba
bbaa

b aab
aabaa

aa bbb
baa

Comment: problem is there is not much that i know about this concept.

Comment: The `<palindrome> ::= <letter>*` rule is too generous, I think.  You need to allow 0 or 1 letter only, not zero or more.

Comment: Yep, all mentionings about repetitions are EBNF, no idea how to express the "*" in the last-but-one line in normal BNF...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler so in that case just use (a,b) only?

Comment: Ah, I just realize: probably my concept cannot be expressed in BNF, since it cannot be expressed by a finite state automaton. It would required an endless number of states... So you'd need a turing machine.

Comment: how would you write that ?

Comment: I saw your original solution in other examples on the web, guess that is where you took it from. But I think we agree that "abba" _is_ a palindrome, so the proposed solution is not complete. That is what I try to fix...

Comment: "how would you write that ?" - as mentioned above: I doubt that _can_ be expressed in BNF, since it has higher complexity. Which surprises me too :-)

Comment: I'd probably go with `<palindrome> ::= <letter> | <empty>` where empty denotes no letter.  But it isn't well defined — one advantage of [EBNF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14922242/how-to-convert-bnf-to-ebnf/14922839#14922839).  Note that you don't need to allow for double letters; that's handled by a rule such as `a <palindrome> a` in conjunction with `<palindrome> := <empty>`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler OK, if the alphabet is limited, then indeed this _can_ be expressed by iteration...

Comment: You can just about do it, but it is painful in the extreme to have to write a new term in the main expansion of `<palindrome>` whenever there's a new alphebetic symbol added to the repertoire.  OTOH, most people don't go inventing new characters for the alphabet all that often.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Indeed new characters are defined not _that_ often (though it happens, my native language just received a new one some 8 years ago...), but there are already really many characters...

Comment: <palindromes> ::= <empty>
<palindromes> ::= a
<palindromes> ::= b
<palindromes> ::= a<palindromes>a
<palindromes> ::= b<palindromes>b

Comment: Actually, if the BNF supports 'optional' elements, then `<palindrome> := [ <letter> ]` does the `<letter> | <empty>` job.

Comment: It does support that, but I doubt that <empty> is a palindrome, since I would _not_ consider it to be a word.

Comment: @arkascha i guess the solution that you posted above will work. Hoping i get partial credit for it atleast.

Comment: Let's call the above the result of a combined effort. Allow me to equally spread that upvote to the four of us :)