# How do I Convert EBNF to BNF?

Tags: syntax, bnf, ebnf

I had a question while I was studying for my university project.
I found out about the grammar of BNF and EBNF by searching the internet.

(1) I need to convert this phrase to EBNF.

```
<id> ::= <letter> | <id><letter> | <id><digit>
```

So I did this conversion.

```
<id>::= <letter>( <letter> | <digit> )*
```

Is this grammar is correct, but also how can I express it with a syntax diagram?

(2) Conversely, how can I change this EBNF to BNF?

```
<complex sentence> ::= ‘{’ <sentence> { <sentence> } ‘}’
```

There were many ways to convert from BNF to EBNF on the Internet, but I felt that I lacked information on how to convert EBNF to BNF. I also want to know how this is represented by a syntax diagram.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting BNF to EBNF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101594/converting-bnf-to-ebnf)

Comment: Although [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14922242/how-to-convert-bnf-to-ebnf?rq=1) looks like it has better answers

Answer (score 1):

I don't *believe* that EBNF uses angle brackets (`<`, `>`).

```
id ::= letter ( letter | digit )*
```

And with [Railroad Diagram Generator](https://bottlecaps.de/rr/ui):

[image]